# Сalling the function only for one block, not for the entire document

Tags: javascript, function

I call the function past_dir second time to put content in block '.id23'. However, because of I called this function to put content in block '.id12', current call duplicates content. How I can call the function only for blocks, not for document?

```
let neighbourhoods = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'];

content_dir1 = '';
function past_dir(numth){       
        for (let j in neighbourhoods) {
            content_dir1 += `<div">
                               <input id="${numth}${j}" type="checkbox" />
                               <label for="${numth}${j}"><span>${neighbourhoods[j]}</span></label>
                            </div>`;                                          
                }
        return  content_dir1;               
    }
  
  let direction1 = past_dir('neighb1');
  let direction2 = past_dir('neighb2');
    
    $('.id12').html(direction1);    
    $('.id23').html(direction2)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/pghjnbk9/

Comment: Because you made content_dir1 global, move it inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `content_dir1` should not be a global variable. Each time you call the function `past_dir()` you ADD to the variable with the `+=`. The `+=` is fine as long as the variable `content_dir1` is defined inside the function.

```js
let neighbourhoods = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'];

function past_dir(numth) {
  let content_dir1 = '';
  for (let j in neighbourhoods) {
    content_dir1 += `<div class="fh">
      <input id="${numth}${j}" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="${numth}${j}"><span>${neighbourhoods[j]}</span></label></div>`;
  }
  return content_dir1;
}

let direction1 = past_dir('neighb1');
let direction2 = past_dir('neighb2');

$('.id12').html(direction1);
$('.id23').html(direction2);
```

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="id12 block"></div>
<div class="id23 block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a global variable so you keep appending to it and you do not clear it

```
content_dir1 = '';
function past_dir(numth){
```

should be

```
function past_dir(numth){  
  var content_dir1 = '';
```

So now everytime you run the function, you start with a clean string you can append to.

```js
let neighbourhoods = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'];

function past_dir(numth) {
  var content_dir1 = '';
  for (let j in neighbourhoods) {
    content_dir1 += `<div class="fh">
<input id="${numth}${j}" type="checkbox" />
<label for="${numth}${j}"><span>${neighbourhoods[j]}</span></label>
                                    </div>
                                    `;
  }
  return content_dir1;
}

let direction1 = past_dir('neighb1');
let direction2 = past_dir('neighb2');

$('.id12').html(direction1);
$('.id23').html(direction2);
```

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="id12 block"></div>

<div class="id23 block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the content_dir1 inside the function:

```js
let neighbourhoods = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'];

content_dir1 = '';
function past_dir(numth){   
        content_dir1 = '';
        for (let j in neighbourhoods) {
    content_dir1 += `<div class="fh">
<input id="${numth}${j}" type="checkbox" />
<label for="${numth}${j}"><span>${neighbourhoods[j]}</span></label></div>`;                                       
                }
        return  content_dir1;               
    }
  
  let direction1 = past_dir('neighb1');
    let direction2 = past_dir('neighb2');
    
    $('.id12').html(direction1);    
    $('.id23').html(direction2);
```

```css
.block {margin-top: 20px}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="id12 block"></div>
<div class="id23 block"></div>
```